# SVN Branch To Trunk Merge Issue

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have tried Googling the issue at hand, to no avail. My team is in an interesting situation.

Our release branch needed to be merged back into our trunk. After about 4 weeks of commits, no one had done so (we usually try to do it once a week). A developer then merged the branch to the trunk, but only did a range of revisions that did NOT include all of the revisions to the branch.

Example: we created the branch at commit 1000. Commits 1000-1400 all happened before the first merge. The developer merged commits 1300-1400. All the while, there have been commits to trunk as well.

Another week or two passed, and now we're up to commit 1500. We go to do another merge and of course, it all blows up; we don't have a ton of commits needed for the builds to pass (commits 1000-1300). We can't exactly revert, because we risk ruining all of the changes made to trunk during this whole time.

What are our options? This is a critical merge as our major release is soon; we need to reduce the chance for messing something up as much as possible in a relatively small amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god, that sounds messy...

first thing to do is to kick all the developers off the repo for a few hours, if not days (because its going to take a while and will be stressful, hope you have no plans for the weekend.... ), maybe take your CI system offline for a bit too. (not nessary but it will save a bunch of broken builds)

Then read this : [SVN Manual for dump/load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5)

make a backup copy of your repo's filesystem. (incase you make a mistake. )

```
svnadmin dump REPO_LOCATION_HERE --revision 0:LAST_SAFE_REVISION_NUMBER_HERE > baseline.dumpfile
```

Create another repo, and "load" your dumpfile

```
svnadmin load --force-uuid /opt/subversion/my_new_repo < baseline.dumpfile
```

now go back to your old repo,

```
svn log -r LAST_SAFE_REVISION_NUMBER_HERE:HEAD REPO_LOCATION_HERE > reading.txt
```

go through reading.txt and manually write down what the commits to trunk that are 'valid' and need to be kept, (pretty much everything up to the first merge. ), and dump/load them in manually into the new repo using the abovementioned method.

Now re-do the first merge (and be sure to include all the revisions in the branch this time. )

And here's the fun part, do a svn log --diff from right after the first merge to the second. manually use the linux 'patch' command to patch files in one after each other into the new repo. for the 'dodgy' 100 or so commits., then svn dump/load the remaining good ones (assuming that there are any. )

Finally do a full checkout from your new repo, run all your tests. if they pass move the old repo to a new location, and the new repo into the location of the old one. and tell all your dev's to do a clean checkout and you should be good.

there is a neat tool called tkdiff (part of the tkcvs package) which could help you shortcut this process. a little bit/ try to see the mess caused. )

if at any stage you screw up then move the 'old' repo away to a new location and put a copy of your repo backup in the old repo's location.

Good luck !!!!.

Comment: I accepted your answer because in a worse situation, I believe that would be a good option; however, we were EXTREMELY fortunate to be able to revert the merge and reintegrate everything from the branch back in without anything blowing up. 8.5 hours and a couple of boxes of pizza later and we are good for our release :).  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: that was lucky, The only reason why I answered was because I actually had a similar issue that I personally had to deal with, except ours included a lot of file renaming and re-organization, in the damaging branch, and whitespace changes due to the difference between dos and unix line endings.